# Dúvida sobre tipo de dado banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Vejam esta tabela dos tipos de dados INT no SQL SERVER:

```
tinyint  | 0 a 255                                        | 1 byte
smallint |-2^15 (-32.768) a 2^15-1 (32.767)               | 2 bytes
int      |-2^31 (-2.147.483.648) a 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647) | 4 bytes
```

Sobre a terceira coluna (Armazenamento) diz que um campo do tipo INT ocupa 4 bytes. Mas significa que qualquer `INSERT`  que eu der e preencher este campo ele vai consumir 4 bytes? Independentemente do numero, por exemplo, "2" ou "25874524" ainda vai consumir 4 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, pois você irá utilizar todos os 4 bytes para representar o número.

Por exemplo, seguindo a ordem de escrita dos bits da direita para a esquerda, é assim que você escreve os seguintes valores como inteiros de 4 bytes:

0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
1: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
128: 00000000 00000000 0000000 10000000
1025: 00000000 0000000 00000100 00000001

etc., etc. até o valor mais alto possível. Dependendo da implementação (e infelizmente eu não conheco a do MySql), o bit mais afastado do primeiro indica sinal ao invés de um valor (i.e.: 0 indica +, 1 indica -, ou vice-versa).

Isso pode parecer desperdício de espaço. Mas existem diversos motivos para que seja feito dessa forma. Vou citar apenas o que considero mais forte: se o número de bytes nos números fosse variável, você teria que interpretar uma sequência de tamanho variável para saber o valor real do número. Por exemplo, se a quantidade fosse variável, e eu lesse o seguinte byte:

00010000

Como eu saberia se o valor é 16, ou algum valor maior somado a 16? Teria que ler outro byte, e outro, e outro, sempre testando por algum sinal de parada.

Mas se você tem certeza de que todos os seus inteiros possuem uma quantidade fixa de bytes, você pode pegar essa quantidade fixa de dados do disco primeiro e ler depois.

Em geral, ler vários bytes de uma única vez de um dispositivo como um disco, memória flash e mesmo memória RAM é muito mais rápido do que ler a mesma quantidade de bytes com mais de uma operação de leitura. Então, no final das contas, a perda de espaço é justificada pelo ganho na velocidade e na simplificação da leitura.